# Javascript Extract element in array based off another element

Tags: javascript, arrays

new to Javascript and have a basic question.

Say I have the following array of arrays:

```
const cities = [
  {
    "id": 4048332,
    "name": "Aurora",
    "state": "IN",
    "country": "US",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -84.901337,
      "lat": 39.056999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4048388,
    "name": "New Pekin",
    "state": "IN",
    "country": "US",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -86.016922,
      "lat": 38.505058
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4254010,
    "name": "Austin",
    "state": "IN",
    "country": "US",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -85.808029,
      "lat": 38.758389

    }
}
```

Say I have a variable that is a user input of a city, and if the city matches one of the cities listed in the array return the city ID relative to that array.  So if a user inputs "New Pekin", how would I go about getting a return of 4048388?  Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? [This might be a good place to start.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: That's an array of **objects**, not an array of arrays.

Comment: You could use something like this:

```javascript

function(searchKey) {

    let keysToSearch = ['name']

    return cities.filter(city => {
        return keysToSearch.some(key => {
            if (city[key]) {
                return city[key].includes(searchKey)
            }
            return false
        })
    })
}

```
This will return a list of cities where one of the properties you specify in the `keysToSearch` include the `searchKey`.

Comment: @Souf may as well post that as the answer.

Comment: I couldn't because the post is closed :/